improve my f1_score for classification - pandas/sklearn
I would like advice on how to improve my f1_score for classification. I currently have something around 0.57. Dataset:
lotWaferDie - lot, board and chip on which defects were measured

string values like W02-D12_11,..

XRel - relative position of the defect in the axis
X
YRel - relative position of the defect in the Y axis
XSize - the size of the defect in the X axis
YSize - the size of the defect in the Y axis
DefArea - defect area
DefSize - the size of the defect
dieRow - the row of the defect on the board
dieCol - defect column on the board
xidx - index of the defect line on the board
yidx - index of the defect column on the board
fail - 1/0 what i predict
Here are some steps I've tried
I tried to cut the lotWaferDie into 3 parts.
As for the xidx and yidx column bars, I'm not sure of their importance, but removing them doesn't make a difference
df[['L', 'W', 'D']] = df['lotWaferDie'].str.split('-|_', expand=True)
df = df.drop(columns=['lotWaferDie'])

# use one-hot encoding
for col in df.select_dtypes(object).columns:
    df = pd.concat([
        df.drop(col, axis=1), pd.get_dummies(df[col], prefix=('d_' + col))
    ], axis=1)


# 
Xtrain, Xrest, ytrain, yrest = train_test_split(
    df.drop(columns=['fail']), df.fail, test_size=0.4, random_state=random_seed, stratify=df.fail
)


Xtest, Xval, ytest, yval = train_test_split(
    Xrest, yrest, test_size=0.5, random_state=random_seed, stratify=yrest
)

param_grid = {
    'max_depth': range(1, 40), 
    'criterion': ['entropy']
}
param_comb = ParameterGrid(param_grid)
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
val_acc = []
param_f1_pairs = []  

for i,params in enumerate(param_comb):
    dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=params['max_depth'], criterion=params['criterion'])
    dt.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
    
    val_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(yval, dt.predict(Xval)))
    val_score = accuracy_score(yval, dt.predict(Xval))
    print(f"Iteration {i+1}/{len(param_comb)} - Validation Score: {val_score:.4f} - Parameters: {params}")
    
    predicted_classes = dt.predict(Xtest)
    f1 = f1_score(ytest, predicted_classes)
    param_f1_pairs.append((params, f1))  
    print("F1 skóre:", f1)

all program: https://onecompiler.com/python/42antqzp8
dataset: https://easyupload.io/3y2kou
